# Difference between StringUtils' method and String's method

Tags: java

Is there any difference between `StringUtills.endWith("str","substr")` and `str.endWith("substr")`?

Comment: No, they are identical in that neither of them exists.  Perhaps you meant `endsWith`.  Also, they will only behave similarly if `str` has the value `"str"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StringUtils` methods are null-safe.

So if str is null  you do not get a `nullpointerexception` if you are using StringUtils.

For more informations see the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#endsWith(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).